# How would you turn the results of this into a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

I can get this to work interactively in SQL Server Management Studio but need these results in a view.  I'm somewhat new to T-SQL.  Is there an easy way to perhaps put this in a table (instead of a view) and have it run on a scheduled basis every morning?

```
Declare @Tempresults TABLE
(
 ID varchar(100),
 MinLine varchar(100),
 MaxLine varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Tempresults (ID, MinLine, MaxLine)
Select PACK_ID, Min(LINE) as MinLine, MAX(Line) as MaxLine 
from DESC 
group by PACK_ID


Declare @Tempresults2 TABLE
(
 ID2 varchar(100),
    MinLine2 varchar(100),
    MaxLine2 varchar(100),
 FirstEntry varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO @Tempresults2 (ID2, MinLine2, MaxLine2, FirstEntry)
select ID, MinLine, MaxLine, PACK_DESC as FirstEntry
 from @Tempresults b, DESC a
 where b.ID = a.PACK_ID and b.MinLine = a.line


Declare @Tempresults3 TABLE
(
 ID3 varchar(100),
 MinLine3 varchar(100),
 MaxLine3 varchar(100),
 LastEntry varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO @Tempresults3 (ID3, MinLine3, MaxLine3, LastEntry)
select ID, MinLine, MaxLine, PACK_DESC as LastEntry
 from @Tempresults b, DESC a
 where b.ID = a.PACK_ID and b.MaxLine = a.line

select a.id2 as ID, b.lastentry as MaxDesc, a.firstentry as MinDesc 
from @Tempresults2 a, @Tempresults3 b
Where a.ID2 = b.ID3
group by ID2, FirstEntry, LastEntry
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
SELECT 
    a.id2 AS ID, 
    MaxDesc, 
    MinDesc 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        PACK_ID AS ID, 
        MinLine, 
        MaxLine, 
        d.PACK_DESC AS MaxDesc, 
        a.PACK_DESC AS MinDesc 
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            PACK_ID, 
            MIN(LINE) AS MinLine, 
            MAX(Line) AS MaxLine 
        FROM 
            DESC 
        GROUP BY 
            PACK_ID
        ) b INNER JOIN
    DESC a ON 
        b.ID = a.PACK_ID AND 
        b.MinLine = a.line INNER JOIN
    DESC d ON
        b.ID = d.PACK_ID  AND
        b.MaxLine = d.line
    )
GROUP BY 
    ID2, FirstEntry, LastEntry
```